# why will the application show after sys.exit command?

Tags: python, ipython

I'm following this tutorial:

http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/firstprograms/

and on the very first example I don't understand why does the application show only after the command:

```
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Also, I modified the code slightly to test things

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    w.resize(250,150)
    w.move(300,300)
    w.setWindowTitle("Title")
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

If I run this in the terminal and comment out the last line it will only show the window after running the last line.

I don't quite understand what the last line does.

EDIT:

I'm also confused as to why there isn't a reference of `app` and `w` i'd expect some kind of indication that `w` is a child or something of `app`.

I'm running it in Spyder and an IPython interpreter.

Comment: follow up posted:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689313/why-is-there-no-reference-between-the-app-and-the-widget

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's equivalent to

```
status = app.exec_()   # run app, show window, wait for input
sys.exit(status)       # terminate program with a status code returned from app
```

Comment: so `app.exec_()` is saying execute (hence exec?) the app? And the other thing is how is the `app` variable related to the in between code? there isn't any reference or anything similar which is confusing me...

Comment: Roughly yes. "Perform the `exec_` procedure of the `app` object". I'm sorry, I din't understand your second question.

Comment: PyQT class reference is [here](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/classes.html).

Comment: i'm waiting to post a follow up... there is a 20 minute rule... I was referring to the block of code between where the two statements using `app` are.

Comment: follow up posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689313/why-is-there-no-reference-between-the-app-and-the-widget

Answer (score 3):

The last line is two functions. First it runs `app.exec_()` (which shows the main window of your application), then when that function ends, it passes the return value to as a parameter to [`sys.exit`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.exit), which ends the program and sends the return value to the operating system (you can see this on *nix systems with `echo $?` after the program ends).

The reason it doesn't immediately exit is that Python can't execute `sys.exit` until it knows the value of the parameter to it, and it won't know that until `app.exec_()` finishes.

Comment: follow up posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15689313/why-is-there-no-reference-between-the-app-and-the-widget