# why is there no reference between the app and the widget?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, ipython

This is a follow up to 
[why will the application show after sys.exit command?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15688889/why-will-the-application-show-after-sys-exit-command)

I'm following this tutorial:

http://zetcode.com/tutorials/pyqt4/firstprograms/

I modified the code slightly to test things

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = QtGui.QWidget()
    w.resize(250,150)
    w.move(300,300)
    w.setWindowTitle("Title")
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I'm confused as to why there isn't a reference of `app` and `w` i'd expect some kind of indication that `w` is a child or something of `app`.

I'm running it in Spyder and an IPython interpreter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any GUI application using Qt, there is precisely one QApplication object, no matter whether the application has 0, 1, 2 or more windows at any given time. All windows are automatically managed by the Application.

You do have to initialize it and to get a hold of it to `exec` it though.

You must create the Application before any other GUI objects (because they are managed by it).

[Detailed Description of the QApplication object](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qapplication.html#details)